# How many different sizes should a shop serve for a flat white?

Tags: espresso, cup, coffee-shop

Sometimes when I visit a shop they simply list flat white. Other times there are many many options for size. What is the correct way to serve a flat white?

Answer (score 1):

It is common for a shop to offer only one size of flat white because a flat is a very basic drink. It's a shot of espresso with foam added. That's all.

If you further dilute a flat white by adding milk, you have a latte. If you multiply a flat white by using two or more shots of espresso, you end up with two or more flat whites.

If you run a shop and the flat white is a popular drink, add a double size and see how it fares. Go from there based on product performance. I'd not go more than a triple though because three shots of espresso in one drink is getting a little bananas.

Comment: It's actually a double shot with very silky milk and little foam added. Hence the name "flat" white. If you look at it from the side it should only have a thin layer of silky micro foam. An espresso with foam on top would be a classic espresso macchiato.

Comment: Machiato is Italian and flat white is from Australia/New Zealand. Machiato uses significantly less milk to "mark" the coffee. Flat white uses a fair bit more milk and makes a sweeter drink. Of course, different coffee shops serve clientele with different preferences. Americans for example aren't happy with such small drinks, so most American coffee shops double or triple classic recipes. Some deviate entirely from the classic recipes, like Starbucks. When in doubt, ask the barista.